# How to call a procedure with inserts and an out parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a procedure to automate some inserts based on an IN parameter. I also want to know if the inserts fail or not, so I created an exception that returns me a 'FAIL' if any error occurs. I have the procedure completed, and I'm sure it will do the inserts if I just run the procedure, but I need to use this inside of another one, therefore I need to be able to access the status of the inserts. Usually I would select * into variable, but because I have inserts in my procedure I get errors about using inserts inside of a query. Please help me find a way to be able to call my procedure to know if they fail and act accordingly.

Here is a sample set of data and a sample procedure with similar functionality to mine:

```sql
create table datatable(val1 INT, val2 INT, val3 INT);

create procedure insert_datatable(n in int, status out varchar2) is
status varchar2 := 'good';
begin
for i in 1.. n loop
    insert into datatable(val1,val2,val3) values (1,2,n)
end loop
commit;
exception
    when others then
        rollback;
        status := 'fail'
        return status
end;
```

The above proc would then need to be called to 1. do the inserts and 2. tell me if they failed. I tried (without success):

```sql
select insert_datatable into insert_status from dual;
```

Comment: give a length for `varchar2` such as `varchar2(15)`, put semi-colons at the end of  `status := 'fail'` and `return status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare a `status` variable local to the procedure; its already declared as an `OUT` parameter. You also should leave the `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` statements to the block where you call the procedure; this allows multiple procedures to be called in one transaction and then can commit them all or roll them all back. You also don't use `RETURN` statements in a procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_datatable(
  n in int,
  status out varchar2
)
IS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP
    insert into datatable(val1,val2,val3) values (1,2,n);
  END LOOP;
  status := 'good';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    status := 'fail';
END;
/
```

Then you can call it using PL/SQL (you can't use procedures in a query, you'd need a function for that):

```sql
DECLARE
  p_status VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  insert_datatable(
    n      => 3,
    status => p_status
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_status );
END;
/
```

Which outputs `good` and puts values into the table:

> ```
> VAL1 | VAL2 | VAL3
> ---: | ---: | ---:
>    1 |    2 |    3
>    1 |    2 |    3
>    1 |    2 |    3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9d5867ecb5d98135bd979e31c1e862dd)*

Comment: Thanks to you and Bob Jarvis. Apologize for syntax errors I had little time to recreate a sample proc and I am much more familiar with functions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please correct the obvious syntax errors such as missing semicolons, etc. SO is not a code-checking service. Please respect the people who volunteer their time and effort here by posting code which will compile. Thanks.

Second, you've attempted to return a value using the `RETURN` statement. PROCEDURE's don't return anything.

Third, you can't call a PROCEDURE from a query. You'd need to make it a FUNCTION and have it return a value.

Lastly, transaction control statements (COMMIT, ROLLBACK) in a subroutine called from a query are not allowed. I suppose you could use an autonomous transaction in your function, but frankly I think that's a bad idea. Your best bet is to call your procedure from an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  intVar     INT;
  strStatus  VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  insert_datatable(n => intVar, status => strStatus);
END;
```